# Compiler Errors in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, augmented-reality

Hi this might seem like a stupid but i'm a student trying to make an augmented reality application and i found this toolkit for AR stuff which i've brought into flash builder but i've never really used any external toolkits before and i'm not really sure what i'm doing.

At the moment it keeps saying that it's trying to access an undefined property @ ar_cam, ar_vid, ar_marker, & ar_params.

I'm not sure if i am doing something wrong or if it has something to do with how i am using the external toolkit.

*Any advice anybody could give me with this would be greatly appreciated.*

This is my code so far:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.core.FLARCode;
    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.core.param.FLARParam;

    [SWF(width="320", height="480", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="marker.pat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private var marker:Class;

        [Embed(source="camera_para.dat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private var cam_params:Class;

        public function Main()
        {
            createFLAR();
            createCam();
        }
        public function createFLAR()
        {
            ar_params = new FLARParam();
            ar_marker = new FLARCode(16, 16);
            ar_params.loadARParam(new cam_params() as ByteArray);
            ar_marker.loadARPatt(new marker());
        }
        public function createCam()
        {
            ar_vid = new Video(320, 480);
            ar_cam = Camera.getCamera();
            ar_cam.setMode(320, 480, 30);
            ar_vid.attachCamera(ar_cam);
            addChild(ar_vid);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not creating the variables for the objects in either of those functions so replace

```
ar_params = new FLARParam();
ar_marker = new FLARCode(16, 16);
```

with

```
var ar_params:FLARParam = new FLARParam();
var ar_marker:FLARCode = new FLARCode(16, 16);
```

and

```
ar_vid = new Video(320, 480);
ar_cam = Camera.getCamera();
```

with

```
var ar_vid:Video = new Video(320, 480);
var ar_cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); //I don't know if Camera is right after the : so you could use * if that doesn't work
```

In actionscript 3 the syntax is as follows:

```
var [nameOfObject]:[typeOfObject] = new [ObjectClass](params);
```

Good luck

Comment: thanks that got rid of those errors anyway. it's always a stupid mistake.